# Windows Server 2003 -Ktpass - crypto: enum value 'rc4-hmac' is not known

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, windows-server-2003, ktpass

I'm trying to create a keytab with Ktpass on a Windows Server 2003.

```
Ktpass -princ host/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG -mapuser host -pass password -crypto rc4-hmac -out UNIXhost.keytab
```

I get the following error:

```
crypto: enum value 'rc4-hmac' is not known.
Error: argument for option "crypto" must be one of the following values:
DES-CBC-CRC : for compatibility
DES-CBC-MD5 : default
Command line options:

---------------------most useful args
[- /]          out : Keytab to produce
[- /]        princ : Principal name (user@REALM)
[- /]         pass : password to use
                     use "*" to prompt for password.
---------------------less useful stuff
[- /]      mapuser : map princ (above) to this user account (default: don't)
[- /]        mapOp : how to set the mapping attribute (default: add it)
[- /]        mapOp :  is one of:
[- /]        mapOp :        add : add value (default)
[- /]        mapOp :        set : set value
[- +]      DesOnly : Set account for des-only encryption (default:do)
[- /]           in : Keytab to read/digest
---------------------options for key generation
[- /]       crypto : Cryptosystem to use
[- /]       crypto :  is one of:
[- /]       crypto : DES-CBC-CRC : for compatibility
[- /]       crypto : DES-CBC-MD5 : default
[- /]        ptype : principal type in question
[- /]        ptype :  is one of:
[- /]        ptype : KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL : The general ptype-- recommended
[- /]        ptype : KRB5_NT_SRV_INST : user service instance
[- /]        ptype : KRB5_NT_SRV_HST : host service instance
[- /]         kvno : Override Key Version Number
                     Default: query DC for kvno.  Use /kvno 1 for Win2K compat.
[- +]       Answer : +Answer answers YES to prompts.  -Answer answers NO.
[- /]       Target : Which DC to use.  Default:detect
```

I have two questions:

***1)*** This I'm intendo to achieve single sign on to Windows users with imap service is on a Centos 6. Although you can use "-crypto rc4-hmac" can also serve DES-CBC-CRC or DES-CBC-MD5?. I believe that Windows customers have all encrypted ticket rc4-hmac and this will not allow things work and I suspect that one of my problems is out there.

***2)*** There are way to allow Windows Server 2003 you can have the option rc4-hmac?.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
/crypto RC4-HMAC-NT
```

or

```
/crypto all
```